# Configure Logitech G600 mouse on MBP Catalina

Tags: mouse

I have a Logitech G600 mouse and have https://www.usboverdrive.com/ installed with the intention configuration of the G keys on the mouse.

usboverdrive works for configuring the mouse movement and speed but I can't figure out how to configure the buttons on the side of the mouse.

usboverdrive has a mode where I presumably can press the button on the side of the mouse and usboverdrive will identify it, but when I press the button it is not being identified.

This is the first time I am using usboverdrive so I am not sure if I am using it correctly.

[EDIT] I first tried to install the Logitech software (GHub) but could not find a way to configure the buttons.  I kept googling and was referred to usboverdrive as an alternative.  It is difficult to google for help with this mouse on mac because the links are dominated by windows oriented links.

Comment: Overdrive doesn't support Apple mice due to proprietary protocols. It's likely the same problem with Logitech beyond the basic buttons.

Answer (score 1):

This page has a video that shows how to configure devices with G-Hub. It should be very close on the Mac. It's far from intuitive...

https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/innovation/g-hub.html

Edit the Desktop: Default Profile

Click on the Assignments icon on the left sidebar

Drag & Drop the key assignment(s) to each button on the pictured mouse

You can create many different profiles for specific games but the Desktop: Default is the one you want to edit for everyday macOS use.

Comment: I could not get GHub to see the G600.  I installed Logitech Gaming and it can see the G600.  I will keep messing with it and report back.

Comment: Go to System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> General.  Do you see a pending kernel extension from Logitech asking to be allowed?  Click Allow.  That's the G-Hub Daemon kernel extension. G-Hub won't work without it.  High Sierra and up block 3rd party kernel extensions by default.  Then reboot and test G-Hub again.

Comment: What is better to use and why:  GHub or Logitech Gaming?

Comment: Decide which you like.  G-Hub offers more options and works across all your Logitech devices, keyboards, headsets, etc. But if Gaming is working then that solves your problem about programming buttons.